# How to use exponent in emacs?

Tags: math, emacs, exponent

I'm new here and new to programming as I've recently enrolled in a Computer Science course.

My question is: how do you denote raising an integer "x" to the  "y" power? I have searched online and have found the command expt however I am unsure of how to write out for example a^b, how would this be written in emacs?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 5):

You might have a look at [Gnu Emacs Math Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Math-Functions.html), where you'll find

```
(expt x y) ;; x^y
```

Comment: i tried this while compiling from terminal and it said i need a ) before b, this is what i am trying to write: x= (-b + sqrt((expt b 2) - 4*a*c)/2*a) && 
(-b - sqrt((expt b 2) - 4*a*c)/2*a);

Comment: **This is the answer to your question.** Please don't pose another question in a comment reply. Consult the manual for information about `-`, `/`,  `*`, and `sqrt`. But start with the Emacs  Lisp Intro manual, for information about Lisp functions in general - Lisp uses prefix notation: `(- 4 2)`, not `4 - 2`.